# Can I do "Local" System calls using query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm currently on a host(A), connecting to a MSSQL database on server(B).
When I do a System call, such as

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'Systeminfo' GO
```

from within MS SQL 2008 it always returns me system information from the client(A) I'm currently running my SQL management tool on.
Is there a possibility to run System calls that will return me information from the server(B)?

Comment: On which SQL Server instance are you connected finally? It will return its information

Comment: I am using an SQL manager from my client to connect to the instance hosted on my server, Your suggestion made me realize I would get more information if I shut down the instance on my client. 
Apparently that  EXEC will automatically try to connect to localhost and if it's not live it will try to turn it on.

Answer (score 0):

I have since asking this question rebooted, and tried all the steps again:
1. Turn off local server
2. Connect to external server 
3. Turn on XP_CMDSHELL command for the external server using

```
 -- To allow advanced options to be changed.  
 EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
 GO  
-- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  
-- To enable the feature.  
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;  
GO  
-- To update the currently configured value for this feature.  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

And then just run

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'Systeminfo';
GO
```

Weird that it works now,because I couldn't get it to work past weeks.